# Keep a persistant state of dropdown box after selected

Tags: php, mysql

As the title suggests I need my dropdown box to keep its value after the user hits submit and not set back to the value. I've uploaded my entire code to better understand what the issue is here since I'm using a mysql query to populate the dropdown.

```
<?php

     $host = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $pass = "";
     $database = "database_camcalc";

     $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($database, $conn);

 $query = "SELECT camera FROM camlist";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

 if (isset($_POST['cameraDD']))
 {
  $camSelect = $_POST['cameraDD'];
 }else{
  $camSelect = 'SNV-5200';
 }

 $dropdown = "Select Camera: <select name='cameraDD' value='$camSelect' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dropdown .= "\r\n\<option value='{$row['camera']}'>{$row['camera']}</option>";
 }
 $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

 $horiQuery = mysql_query("SELECT hori FROM camlist WHERE camera = '$camSelect'");
 if (!$horiQuery) {
   die("Failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 $hori = mysql_fetch_row($horiQuery);

 $sensorSize = mysql_query("SELECT sensor_size FROM camlist WHERE camera = '$camSelect'");
 if (!$sensorSize) {
   die("Failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 $sensorQuery = mysql_query("SELECT camlist.width FROM camlist WHERE camlist.camera = '$camSelect'");
 $sensorRow = mysql_fetch_array($sensorQuery);
 $sensorWidth = floatval($sensorRow['width']);


 $horiFOV = 20;
 $distObj = 35;
 echo "<form method='POST'>",
      "Horizontal Field of View: <input type='text' name='horizontalFOV' value='$horiFOV'>",
      "<br />",
      "Distance to Object: <input type='text' name='distToObj' value='$distObj'>",
      "<br />",
      $dropdown,
      "<br />",
      "<input type='submit' name='submit'>",
      "<br />";

      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
        $horiFOV = $_POST['horizontalFOV'];
      }

 $lensCalc = ($distObj / $horiFOV) * $sensorWidth;
 $ppfCalc = $hori[0] / $horiFOV;

 echo "<div style ='float:left; width:100%;'>Selected Camera: $camSelect</div>";
 echo "<div style ='float:left; width:100%;'>Selected FOV: $horiFOV ft</div>";
 echo '<div style ="float:left; width:100%;">',
      'Pixels Per Foot: ',
      round($ppfCalc),
      '</div>';

 if ($ppfCalc < 19){
   echo "Level of detail: Too Low";
 }elseif ($ppfCalc >= 19 and $ppfCalc <=39){
   echo "Level of detail: Observation";
 }elseif ($ppfCalc >=40 and $ppfCalc <=59){
   echo "Level of detail: Forensic Review";
 }elseif ($ppfCalc >=60 and $ppfCalc <=79){
   echo "Level of detail: Identification";
 }elseif ($ppfCalc >=80 and $ppfCalc <=500){
   echo "Level of detail: Fine";
 }

 echo "<div style ='float:left; width:100%;'>Lens focal length: $lensCalc MM</div>";

?>
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tip: In the future, try no to encapsulate your HTML in PHP. This method creates messy, error-prone code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After this is working properly I'll be creating a html page that refrences the php rather than this way.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. This interface is dangerous, deprecated, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A future-proof replacement is [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) that has the advantage of providing reliable protection [from SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Is there any reason you're doing PHP this way instead of using a [proper framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/)? You're creating a ton of work for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the value of `$camSelect` is equal to the value of `$row['camera']`. Setting the value of the `<select>` element like you do above does nothing.

E.g.,

```
$dropdown = "Select Camera: <select name='cameraDD' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['camera'] == $camSelect) 
        $dropdown .= "\r\n\<option selected='selected' value='{$row['camera']}'>{$row['camera']}</option>";
    else
        $dropdown .= "\r\n\<option value='{$row['camera']}'>{$row['camera']}</option>";
 }
 $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! thank you so much!! Is this the same concept if I wanted to do the same thing for the two textboxes?

Comment: In a textarea you have to set the inner html. E.g., `<textarea name="my_textarea"><?=$_POST['my_textarea']?></textarea>` If you're talking about an input type="text", you have to do it like this: `<input type="text" name="my_input" value="<?=$_POST['my_input]?>"/>`